# How to Inspect Style attributes (Font, Color codes, paddings, etc.) of a mobile app which built using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout, uielement, layout-inspector

In a flutter Mobile application, I need to check the style attributes of each screen. But, I'm unable to inspect it using the android studio layout inspector. It shows a blank screen when we inspect the app. (But it works well with other hybrid applications). I'm using the android studio emulator to run this debug apk file.

[image]

Currently, I only have the debug APK file only. So running the application code directly by myself is not an option for me either.
Can we inspect flutter apps directly with Android studio? Are there any alternatives to inspect these UI style elements? Your help is much appreciated.